# How to adjust 2D grid size according to the user?

Tags: c++, arrays

Not an expert in C++ but I am doing my best, I have this code and I am trying to ask the user to enter a number between 1 and 12, and whatever number they enter, they 2D array will be adjusted to their number, for example:

- Please Enter a number: **3**
- Program will output a 2D array of size 3x3, if they entered "**4**", it would be a 4x4 grid, etc.

I looked at many examples for the past few days but I could not wrap my head around it and apply it to my code. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me, this is what I got to up till now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double Atemp = 0;
double Utemp = 0;
double Working = 0;
double Total = 0;
char Answer = 'x';
int Umain;
const int ROWS = ?;
const int COLS = ?;

typedef float Table[ROWS][COLS];


void displayOverview ();

void playOrQuit();

void outputSubSquare(Table table, int x, int y);
void fillTableWithRands(Table table);
void outputTable(Table table);

void fillIntArray(int array[], int size);
void reverseArray(int array[], int size);
void outputIntArray(int array[], int n);

int main(){

    displayOverview();

    playOrQuit();

    int maxNum = 4;
    int intArray[maxNum];
    fillIntArray(intArray, maxNum);
    outputIntArray(intArray, maxNum);

    srand(time(NULL));
    Table myTable;

    fillTableWithRands(myTable);
    outputTable(myTable);

    return 0;
}

void displayOverview(){

}

void playOrQuit(){

}

void fillIntArray(int array[], int size){

    do{
        cout << "Please Enter numbers between 1 and 12: ";
        cin >> Umain;

        if(Umain <= 12){
            for (Utemp = Umain; Utemp > 0; Utemp--){
                cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 4: ";
                cin >> Atemp;

                for(int i = Atemp; i<0;i++){
                    cin >> array[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "Not within limit :(\n";
        }
    }

    while (Answer == 'y');
}

void fillTableWithRands(Table table){
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            table[i][j]  = rand()%4+ 1;
        }
    }
}


void outputTable(Table table){
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            cout << table[i][j] << " ";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}


void outputIntArray(int array[], int n){
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid(rows, std::vector<int>(cols));`  The big question -- are you allowed to use `std::vector`?  If not [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048)

Comment: If `vector` is not allowed, may I recommend making yourself a simple Matrix class around a dynamically allocated array? Good example here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look at this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431567/how-to-make-an-array-with-a-dynamic-size-general-usage-of-dynamic-arrays-maybe)

You can either use `std::vector` and don't have to care about memory alllocation, or you create a dynamic array and allocate memory based on the given input.

For the dynamic array take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001803/pointer-to-pointer-dynamic-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: How do I use std::vector, where do I place it? sorry if this is a stupid question, but I never used std::vector.

Comment: @LailaMurish *but I never used std::vector.* --Then how were you to complete the assignment if you were not told how to create a dynamic 2 dimensional array?  A tutorial on `vector` usage is way too big of a topic -- that is best learned by reading **good** C++ books and tutorials.

Comment: Yes, I just asked, we are not allowed to use vectors, I don't understand though why? (btw,  was able to work it out thankfully, thank you for your help, truly appreciated).